# bash script to create folder for user at login and set access permissions

Tags: macos, bash, logout

I'm a new Photography technician at a small art school and am responsible for a small mac lab. Unfortunately our IT dept. dosen't offer direct support for macs (only the network) so I've got to roll up my sleeves and learn as I go.

The lab has operated as a single managed login (no password) on all machines for ages, and this has caused a great number of difficulties,  but I'm working to change this to a modle that accepts Active Directory credentials, creating a new user on the fly. On log out that user account will be destroyed to normalise the user environment between each session.

The drawback is that for the few students that do repeated work at a particular station, any files they create will of course be destroyed. As a work around, I'd like to create a login script that creates a safe place for them to save their files on a partitioned drive, and set the permissions for that directory to write only for all other users except admin.

I've cobbled most of this together already - but I'd really love general feedback from my betters (is anything Im doing here unwise) and guidance on how to set the permissions as what I've got here doesn't seem to work, and frankly I've only a loose understanding of the ins and outs of UNIX permissions.

I've set this up as a .command file with execute permissions to test it - and the folder and alias are created as expected, but the owner/group settings aren't taking. - the owner is my admin account, and the group remains 'staff'. I've also set up a 'test' user and a student group.

Many thanks for your thoughts.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create a safe place for users to save their files
# We will destroy this directory if it's empty on log out
# Using sudo for the time being for testing, wont have to when it's run at login by root

# Dont run if user is admin
if [ `whoami` == "comdesadmin" ]; then
exit 1
fi

if [ `whoami` != "comdesadmin" ]; then

#User name
USERNAME="test";
#USERNAME=`whoami` ;

# Group name
USERGROUP=student;
#Set direcory path
USERSAFEFOLDER=/Volumes/nest/$USERNAME

# Create the directory for the user if it isn't there
# user names shouldn't have any spaces so this should be ok
mkdir -p $USERSAFEFOLDER;

# Set the ownership to the current users (as this be being run by root)
sudo chown -R guest $USERSAFEFOLDER;

# Set the group
sudo chgrp $USERGROUP $USERSAFEFOLDER;

# Set write only to everyone else
chmod 700 $USERSAFEFOLDER;

# Make alias on the desktop for them
osascript <<END_SCRIPT
tell application "Finder"
   make new alias to folder (posix file "$USERSAFEFOLDER") at desktop
end tell
END_SCRIPT

echo "Sucess";

fi
exit 0
```

Comment: I recommend asking this question at apple.stackexchange.com for assistance with proper Mac OS X-based user administration.

Comment: I was't aware of apple.stackexchange - good shout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The second `if` is completely unnecessary (`` if [ `whoami` != "comdesadmin" ] ``) because it is direct opposite of the first. You can simply delete that line (and its closing `fi` at the bottom)
2. It can be a good idea to change the first line to `#!/bin/bash -e` that way the script exits immediately when a step fails
3. Instead of including `sudo` for testing, it's easier and better to test without the sudo lines, and by calling the script itself with sudo as a user you want to test with, for example:

   ```
   sudo -u username -g groupname .command
   ```
4. The `chown` and `chgrp` lines should not be necessary when run with `sudo`
5. The `exit 0` at the end is unnecessary since the `echo` command right before that will exit with 0 which will be used as the exit code of the script itself
6. The `;` at at end of lines are unnecessary
7. It's better to use `$()` instead backticks in every way, for example `$(whoami)` instead of `` `whoami` ``

Comment: Thanks very much for those cleanup tips. I threw in the sudo because I wasn't seeing the results from `chown` or `chgrp` and thought it might be a permissions issue. Any ideas as to why these wouldn't apply the correct group or user?

Comment: also can you point me to an article or tut on what your describing in number three - Im not sure Im following you on that one.

Comment: I added #7. As for #3, since you expect the script to be executed by users at login, it's best to test the script by running as one of those users or a test user. Replace `username` and `groupname` in the example command appropriately. As per the `chown`, `chgrp`, I don't really see what you're trying to do. The script is going to run by users on logon, but regular users cannot change ownership of files anyway. I think it's unnecessary, and maybe you are confused.

Comment: Most likely Im confused, but my understanding is that login hooks  run as root so presumed I needed to be explicit about the user and group. Thanks again for your help btw.

Comment: User creation must run as admin, but login scripts should run as the user. Otherwise it would be a security risk. You're totally welcome.

Comment: @orionrush Care to mark as accepted?

Comment: Given't you gave me help, before the topic was uncermoniosly closed - sure! thanks for your help. I've got to get better at writing SE palatable questions. Perhaps Im just sensitive, but There seems to be a concerted effort to down vote and or close questions lately. For example this one which was closed and down voted without feedback - not even put on hold. Im at a loss to see what tone, rules or parameters I've violated given http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: I feel your pain. Truth be told, I think your question was in a gray area. A tip for the future: make your question as short as possible, and stick to the point: "owner/group settings not taking effect in login script". Especially, never ask for code review here. Btw, the "on hold" feature is new, your question was closed before that feature came out, that's why. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/ Anyway, unfair things do happen. Don't take it personally, just move on, keep you head up, don't get discouraged!